# how to call outer class function out of doInBackground within inner AsyncTask class?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I haven't found anything to solve my problem yet... I have to call an outer class method out of the inner class. This is my code (shortened):

```
public class FileBrowser extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

    public void bgTasksFinished(String doneTask, int result) {

        switch(doneTask) {

            case doEncrypt:
                doSomething();
                break;

            case doDecrypt:
                doAnotherThing();
                break;
        }

    private class BgTasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            bgTasksFinished(doneTask, result); // outer class method
        }
    }
}
```

...but this doesn't work.

While debugging I get this (among others):

```
01-10 18:34:10.357: E/AndroidRuntime(29038): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-10 18:34:10.357: E/AndroidRuntime(29038): Process: de.zpit2u.crypt, PID: 29038
01-10 18:34:10.357: E/AndroidRuntime(29038): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-10 18:34:10.357: E/AndroidRuntime(29038):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
01-10 18:34:10.357: E/AndroidRuntime(29038):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
```

Without debugging the app only crashes (calling the outer class method).

Comment: What problem you are getting?

Comment: I think you can new class (outer class) and call it's method or function as nomarly. Or you set method of outer class is static method to call direct (not new class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call outer class methods only in Asynctask.onPostExecute method. This is because the doInBackground method is actually another thread, so you treat it as if it's in another class entirely.

Check out the developer docs or [one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask) of the [many](http://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Executing-Async-Tasks) excellent tutorials available online.

In your case instead of:

```
private class BgTasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        bgTasksFinished(doneTask, result); // outer class method
    }
}
```

Try:

```
private class BgTasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return doneTask;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String doneTask) {
        bgTasksFinished(doneTask, result); // outer class method
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but. Now it looks like this:`@Override
  protected Integer doInBackground(String... params){` Then `@Override
  protected void onPostExecute(int result) {` But there is an error shown: `The method onPostExecute(int) of type FileBrowser.BgTasks must override or implement a supertype method`

Comment: You also need to change private class BgTasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> to private class BgTasks extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>

Comment: That's been already right. Void, Void, Void was only for the posting here. I've solved the problem (and found anoter one). `protected void onPostExecute(int result)` was wrong. The right way is: `protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)`. Eclipse doesn't see any errors now but onPostExecute is never called. While debugging, eclipse means: source not found.

Comment: Could this possibly leak?